# Keep SAS processing after finding errors

Tags: sas

Is there a way to force sas to continue processing, despite finding errors?

I'm appending a large quantity of datasets at the moment, however within the list I of dataset names I have, some don't exist. This is resulting in a bunch of errors and causing SAS to exit with the message "The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could evaluate the existence of a dataset using the EXIST() function and make the execution of the append conditional on the outcome.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000210903.htm

Comment: Thanks! I'll see how it goes.